# Compare date with jodatime

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I try to compare some date with jodaTime, i use week and year to compare date

```
DateMidnight endDate01 = new DateMidnight().withYear(2012).withWeekyear(37);
DateMidnight endDate02 = new DateMidnight().withYear(2012).withWeekyear(38);


endDate01.isBefore(endDate02); //return false
```

I don't understand why endDate01 seem greater the endDate02.

Maybe a bug?

```
DateMidnight endDate01 = new DateMidnight();

endDate01.withYearOfEra(o1.getEndYearPeriod());
endDate01.withWeekOfWeekyear(o1.getEndWeekPeriod());

System.out.println(o1.getEndWeekPeriod() + " " + o1.getEndYearPeriod());
System.out.println(endDate01.getWeekOfWeekyear() + " " + endDate01.getYearOfEra());
```

i get

37 2012

16 2012

should get the same result, no?

Comment: Maybe it's because endDate02 was instantiated a short period of time after endDate01?

Comment: Strange, the same code returns true in my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

those both code work fine

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(); 
dt = dt.withWeekOfWeekyear(29); 
dt = dt.withWeekyear(2011);

DateMidnight dt2 = new DateMidnight().withWeekOfWeekyear(29).withYear(2011);
```

Answer (score 0):

`withWeekyear` isn't the same as `withWeekOfWeekyear`.  I'm not 100% sure what `withWeekyear` does instead, I think if you mean the 37th week of 2012, you should use `withWeekOfWeekyear` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime firstDate = new DateTime();
firstDate.withWeekyear(2012) /* represents the 2012 with number of weeks in it (I thing the algorith is the difference between first week in 1970) */
firstDate.withWeekOfWeekyear(29) /* now you have the 29th week of 2012 */
firstDate.withDayOfWeek(1) /* now you have 29th week of 2012 and Monday */
```

Now you set the date! Set the second this way and compare them.